# What is the correct pronoun agreement?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I'd like to double check the sentence. What is wrong with this pronoun agreement:

> Whichever of the six players hit the most home runs, they win the
>   contest.

Is it correct?

Comment: This is a left dislocation from _Whichever of the six players hit the most home runs wins the contest_. No pronoun is necessary. If one wishes to left-dislocate the sentence, however, the correct pronoun is _they_, unless the players are know to be either all male or all female, in which case the correct pronoun would be _he_ or _she_, respectively.

Comment: The answer depends on whether you want to pass grammar tests, or whether you want to speak the way normal people do.

Comment: The only thing that strikes me as wrong is that unless you know there were several players who tied for most home runs and therefore share the win, it should be “Whichever of the six players **hits** the most home runs, they win the contest”. As John says, you can get rid of the comma and _they_, but there’s nothing wrong with having them there, either.

Comment: @JohnLawler and JanusBahsJacquet, is this the thing now? When I was in high school, something like _he/she_ or _(s)he_ was the gender-uncertain singular. Has _they_ gained acceptance?

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet, doesn't `they` become incorrect if you put `hit` in a singular form?

Comment: @MathieuK. Yes. Singular _they_ has always been used in English, and it's been destigmatised quite a bit (especially outside high school classrooms, which is where most untruths and myths about English prosper and thrive) in the past 50-or-so years. There's even a tag for it here ([tag:singular-they]), check it out.

Comment: @ArsenY.M. No, it doesn't. The test Julia is taking probably expects her to say that it does, but the test is wrong if so, as so many others like it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So are you saying *they hits* is an acceptable form anywhere? Or are you saying it is just *Whichever of the players hits the most runs, they will be rewarded* that is correct?

Comment: [Here's the word on "singular _they_"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf). From a grammar column I used to write for an editors' newsletter.

Comment: We're not responsible for incompetent teachers, textbooks, or exams. Our only responsibility is to the facts.

Comment: @WS2 No no, _they hits_ is only acceptable in a few dialects here and there and is strongly marked as nonstandard. Your second line is right: whoever hits the most runs, they will be rewarded.

Comment: @JohnLawler A comment to your grammar column: while I might notice and/or stumble at it in writing or if the context was unclear, there is nothing about “Jan left me a message saying they'd be back later” that strikes me as being really ungrammatical—just possibly ambiguous. In context, and particularly in natural speech, I'd be quite likely to use a singular _they_ there, and I sincerely doubt I'd notice or be distracted by it if someone else did, too.

Comment: The tenses are kind of messed up. *“Whichever of the six players **hits** the most home runs, they (will) win the contest.”*  If you delete *they*, then it becomes clearer still: *“Whichever of the six players hits the most home runs wins the contest.”* In other words, whoever hits the most homers wins.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it should be "Whichever of the six players hits the most home runs wins the contest." This way, both hits and wins agree with the singular nature of the word "whichever" instead of the word "players" which is not the true subject of the sentence. I don't think a comma is necessary after home runs, because the predicate is actually "whichever of the six players hits the most home runs."

Comment: Hello Wugdog. As others have already said, "Whichever of the six players hit/s the most home runs wins the contest" sound more natural, but that's not what the stupid test is asking for.